# vapor swift custom validator

Tags: swift, validation, passwords, vapor

I'm trying to create a custom password validator in Vapor.
I can't seem to figure out how to make the Matches work.

Comment: I was helped on slack by loganwright an found the solution

Comment: That's great but please post your solution *as an answer* (not in your question). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*Orignally posted as answer by the question author within the question itself.*

The documentation can be found here https://vapor.github.io/documentation/guide/validation.html

```
import Vapor

class PasswordValidation: ValidationSuite {

    static func validate(input value: String) throws {
        // 1 upper 1 lower 1 special 1 number at least 8 long
        let regex =  Matches("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9]).{8}$")

        /*
        let evaluation = Matches.validate(regex)
        try evaluation.validate(input: value)
        */

        let evaluation = OnlyAlphanumeric.self
                         && Count.min(8)
                         && Matches.validate(Matches<regex & value>)

        try evaluation.validate(input: value)
    }

}
```